# How to make a certain number of functions run parallel in loop in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a way to run 3 same-functions at once in a loop and wait until it finish and continues to run another 3 same-functions. I think it involves a loop, promise API. But my solution is fail. It would be great if you could tell me what did I do wrong and how to fix it.

Here is what I have done so far:

---

I have a download function (call `downloadFile`), an on-hold function (call `runAfter`) and a multi download function (call `downloadList`). They look like this:

```
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const { join } = require('path')
const chalk = require('chalk') // NPM
const mime = require('./MIME') // A small module read Json and turn it to object. It returns a file extension string.

exports.downloadFile = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(url, res => {
        console.log('Accessing:', chalk.greenBright(url))
        console.log(res.statusCode, res.statusMessage)
        // console.log(res.headers)

        const ext = mime(res)
        const name = url
            .replace(/\?.+/i, '')
            .match(/[\ \w\.-]+$/i)[0]
            .substring(0, 250)
            .replace(`.${ext}`, '')
        const file = `${name}.${ext}`
        const stream = fs.createWriteStream(join('_DLs', file))

        res.pipe(stream)
        res.on('error', reject)

        stream
            .on('open', () => console.log(
                chalk.bold.cyan('Download:'),
                file
            ))
            .on('error', reject)
            .on('close', () => {
                console.log(chalk.bold.cyan('Completed:'), file)
                resolve(true)
            })
    })
    req.on('error', reject)
    req.end()
})

exports.runAfter = (ms, url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.downloadFile(url)
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject)
    }, ms);
})

/* The list param is Array<String> only */
exports.downloadList = async (list, options) => {
    const opt = Object.assign({
        thread: 3,
        delayRange: {
            min: 100,
            max: 1000
        }
    }, options)

    // PROBLEM
    const multiThread = async (pos, run) => {
        const threads = []
        for (let t = pos; t < opt.thread + t; t++) threads.push(run(t))
        return await Promise.all(threads)
    }

    const inQueue = async run => {
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += opt.thread)
            if (opt.thread > 1) await multiThread(i, run)
            else await run(i)
    }

    const delay = range => Math.floor(
        Math.random() * (new Date()).getHours() *
        (range.max - range.min) + range.min
    )

    inQueue(i => this.runAfter(delay(opt.delayRange), list[i]))
}
```

The `downloadFile` will download anything from the link given. The `runAfter` will delay a random ms before excute `downloadFile`. The `downloadList` receive a list of URL and pass each of it to `runAfter` to download. And that (`downloadList`) is where the trouble begin.

If I just pass the whole list through simple loop and execute a single file at once. It's easy. But if I pass a large requests, like a list with 50 urls. It would take long time. So I decide to make it run parallel at 3 - 5 `downloadFile` at once, instead of one `downloadFile`. I was thinking about using `async/await` and `Promise.all` to solve the problem. However, it's crash. Below is the NodeJs report:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4124:01EF5068]    75085 ms: Scavenge 491.0 (493.7) -> 490.9 (492.5) MB, 39.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.083, current mu = 0.028) allocation failure
[4124:01EF5068]    75183 ms: Scavenge 491.4 (492.5) -> 491.2 (493.2) MB, 29.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.083, current mu = 0.028) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00B879E7]
Security context: 0x03b40451 <JSObject>
    1: multiThread [04151355] [<project folder>\inc\Downloader.js:~62] [pc=03C87FBF](this=0x03cfffe1 <JSGlobal Object>,0,0x041512d9 <JSFunction (sfi = 03E2E865)>)
    2: inQueue [041513AD] [<project folder>\inc\Downloader.js:70] [bytecode=03E2EA95 offset=62](this=0x03cfffe1 <JSGlobal Object>,0x041512d9 ...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200428.000236.4124.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
```

Apparently, a sub-function of `downloadList` (`multiThread`) is a cause but I couldn't read those number (seems like a physical address of RAM or something), so I have no idea how to fix it. I'm not a professional engineer so I would appreciate if you could give me a good explanation.

Addition information:

- NodeJs version: 12.13.1
- Localhost: Aspire SW3-013 > 1.9GB (2GB in spec) / Intel Atom CPU Z3735F
- Connecting to Internet via WiFi (Realtek drive)
- OS: Windows 10 (no other choice)

In case you might ask:

- Why wrapping Promise for `downloadFile`? For further application, like I can put it in other app which only require one download at a time.
- Does `runAfter` important? Maybe no, just a little challenges for myself. But it could be useful if servers require delay download time.
- Homework or Business? None, hobby only. I plan to build a app to fetch and download image from API of Unsplash. So I prefer a good explanation what I did wrong and how to fix it rather then a code that simple works.

Comment: This line, `for (let t = pos; t < opt.thread + t; t++) threads.push(run(t))`, is that a typo? As `t` is always smaller than `opt.thread + t` in your case, which means an infinite loop.

Comment: Does this answer to your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442455/execute-promise-in-synchronous-batches-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-loop in `multiThread` never ends because your continuation condition is `t < opt.thread + t`. This will **always** be `true` if `opt.thread` is not zero. You will have an infinite loop here, and that's the cause of your crash.

I suspect you wanted to do something like this:

```
const multiThread = async (pos, run) => {
  const threads = [];
  for (let t = 0; t < opt.thread && pos+t < list.length; t++)  {
    threads.push(run(pos + t));
  }
  return await Promise.all(threads);
};
```

The difference here is that the continuation condition for the loop should be limiting itself to a maximum of `opt.thread` times, and also not going past the end of the number of entries in the `list` array.

If the `list` variable isn't global (ie, `list.length` is not available in the `multiThread` function), then you can leave out the second part of the condition and just handle it in the `run` function like this so that any values of `i` past the end of the list are ignored:

```
inQueue(i => {
  if (i < list.length) this.runAfter(delay(opt.delayRange), list[i])
})
```

Comment: It's silly me to make such a mistake in the loop like that. And here I thought I made some terrible mistake in using too much Promises or sth. Thank you very much for your good and clear explanation.